# How to get a transparent Icon in GWT Maps

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

Looking for a way to get an icon to be transparent so that you can still see parts of the map under it when used as a marker.  Anybody know which function in either icon or marker can be used to accomplish this?  Or if it's a CSS thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a PNG/GIF with a transparencies, that would do the trick, also ensure that the container you are placing it on has no background color. Also consider that [support for images with alpha transparency](http://caniuse.com/#search=png) varies from browser to browser.